# How to extract excel column data into python list using pandas from merged cell

Tags: python, pandas

i'm trying to extract 'Country' column data into python list using pandas. Below the code i used to. Also attached excel sheet and output.

code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
open_file = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name=0)
df = list(open_file['Country'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
[nan, 'Great Britain', 'China ', 'Russia', 'United States', 'Korea', 'Japan', 'Germany']
```

Process finished with exit code 0

In the output i can see 'nan' because in the sheet two cells are merged into one. How to avoid this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60KiN.png)

Comment: do you mind sharing this data as an excel file, so I or anyone else can have a go at it?

Comment: please provide a [mcve] and see [ask] you have `nan` because column `A1:A` has no data.

Comment: You should also try to set the column names in just one row

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', header[0,1])
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x if not 'Unnamed' in str(x) else '')
```

Now the headers are in the form of tuples. For ex, to access `Country` or Column `Gold`, you need to write something like below statements

```
print(df[('Country', '')])
print(df[('Media Tally', 'Gold')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use header=1 and then you can use it with unnamed :0 or 1 or 2 to get column values to list

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name=0, header=1)
print(df['Unnamed: 0'].to_list())
```